# Cygwin/LaTeX - "I can't find the format file 'latex.fmt'!

Tags: cygwin

I am running Cygwin/X X Server Version 1.18.2 and installed the ENTIRE TeX package because I couldn't get latex to run. I've used LaTeX and Cygwin for years…but got a new computer and had to install from scratch. Here's the error I keep getting:

```
$ latex a
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015/Cygwin) (preloaded format=latex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.

kpathsea: Running mktexfmt latex.fmt
mktexfmt: mktexfmt is using the following fmtutil.cnf files (in precedence order):
mktexfmt:   /home/hawkise1/.config/texmf/web2c/fmtutil.cnf
mktexfmt:   /usr/share/texmf-dist/web2c/fmtutil.cnf
mktexfmt: mktexfmt is using the following fmtutil.cnf file for writing changes:
mktexfmt:   /home/hawkise1/.config/texmf/web2c/fmtutil.cnf
mktexfmt [INFO]: Disabled formats: 56
I can't find the format file `latex.fmt'!
```

I have changed all permissions in Cygwin, ensured my path is correct, ensured `TEXMFCNF` is not set, ran `texhash`, `texconfig confall`, `texconfig init`, `fmtutil-sys --all`

…nothing seems to work. Is this a bug?

Comment: `/home/hawkise1/.config/texmf/web2c/fmtutil.cnf` looks suspicious I'd remove that since you shouldn't need a local config, and something has disabled all formats