# No formats available after installation of texlive

Tags: texlive, cygwin

After installation of TexLive under Cygwin any attempt at building a .tex file fails with an error that the specified format is not available:

```
$ latex test.tex                                                                       
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016/Cygwin) (preloaded format=latex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.

kpathsea: Running mktexfmt latex.fmt
mktexfmt: mktexfmt is using the following fmtutil.cnf files (in precedence order):
mktexfmt: mktexfmt is using the following fmtutil.cnf file for writing changes:
mktexfmt:   /home/gecko/.config/texmf/web2c/fmtutil.cnf
mktexfmt [INFO]: writing formats under /home/gecko/.cache/texmf/web2c
mktexfmt [INFO]: did not find entry for byfmt=latex, skipped
mktexfmt [INFO]: Total formats: 0
mktexfmt [INFO]: exiting with status 0
I can't find the format file `latex.fmt'!
```

The specified `fmtutil.cnf` file doesn't exist.

I've read elsewhere to run `fmtutil-sys --all`, which does the following:

```
fmtutil: fmtutil is using the following fmtutil.cnf files (in precedence order):
fmtutil: fmtutil is using the following fmtutil.cnf file for writing changes:
fmtutil:   /etc/texmf/web2c/fmtutil.cnf
fmtutil [INFO]: writing formats under /var/lib/texmf/web2c
Use of uninitialized value $whatarg in concatenation (.) or string at /usr/bin/fmtutil line 426.
fmtutil [INFO]: did not find entry for all=, skipped
fmtutil [INFO]: Total formats: 0
```

Again, the specified fmtutil.cnf file doesn't exist.

Installation produced the following, which suggests things went wrong:

```
Running /etc/postinstall/libpaper.sh
Running /etc/postinstall/texlive-collection-basic.sh
fmtutil: fmtutil is using the following fmtutil.cnf files (in precedence order):
fmtutil: fmtutil is using the following fmtutil.cnf file for writing changes:
fmtutil:   /etc/texmf/web2c/fmtutil.cnf
fmtutil [WARNING]: Format/engine combination luatex/luatex is not defined.
fmtutil [WARNING]: Cannot (de)activate it.
fmtutil [INFO]: exiting with status -1
fmtutil: fmtutil is using the following fmtutil.cnf files (in precedence order):
fmtutil: fmtutil is using the following fmtutil.cnf file for writing changes:
fmtutil:   /etc/texmf/web2c/fmtutil.cnf
fmtutil [WARNING]: Format/engine combination dviluatex/luatex is not defined.
fmtutil [WARNING]: Cannot (de)activate it.
fmtutil [INFO]: exiting with status -1
fmtutil: fmtutil is using the following fmtutil.cnf files (in precedence order):
fmtutil: fmtutil is using the following fmtutil.cnf file for writing changes:
fmtutil:   /etc/texmf/web2c/fmtutil.cnf
fmtutil [WARNING]: Format/engine combination luajittex/luajittex is not defined.
fmtutil [WARNING]: Cannot (de)activate it.
fmtutil [INFO]: exiting with status -1
fmtutil: fmtutil is using the following fmtutil.cnf files (in precedence order):
fmtutil: fmtutil is using the following fmtutil.cnf file for writing changes:
fmtutil:   /etc/texmf/web2c/fmtutil.cnf
fmtutil [WARNING]: Format/engine combination mf/mf-nowin is not defined.
fmtutil [WARNING]: Cannot (de)activate it.
fmtutil [INFO]: exiting with status -1
fmtutil: fmtutil is using the following fmtutil.cnf files (in precedence order):
fmtutil: fmtutil is using the following fmtutil.cnf file for writing changes:
fmtutil:   /etc/texmf/web2c/fmtutil.cnf
fmtutil [WARNING]: Format/engine combination pdftex/pdftex is not defined.
fmtutil [WARNING]: Cannot (de)activate it.
fmtutil [INFO]: exiting with status -1
fmtutil: fmtutil is using the following fmtutil.cnf files (in precedence order):
fmtutil: fmtutil is using the following fmtutil.cnf file for writing changes:
fmtutil:   /etc/texmf/web2c/fmtutil.cnf
fmtutil [WARNING]: Format/engine combination etex/pdftex is not defined.
fmtutil [WARNING]: Cannot (de)activate it.
fmtutil [INFO]: exiting with status -1
fmtutil: fmtutil is using the following fmtutil.cnf files (in precedence order):
fmtutil: fmtutil is using the following fmtutil.cnf file for writing changes:
fmtutil:   /etc/texmf/web2c/fmtutil.cnf
fmtutil [WARNING]: Format/engine combination pdfetex/pdftex is not defined.
fmtutil [WARNING]: Cannot (de)activate it.
fmtutil [INFO]: exiting with status -1
fmtutil: fmtutil is using the following fmtutil.cnf files (in precedence order):
fmtutil: fmtutil is using the following fmtutil.cnf file for writing changes:
fmtutil:   /etc/texmf/web2c/fmtutil.cnf
fmtutil [WARNING]: Format/engine combination tex/tex is not defined.
fmtutil [WARNING]: Cannot (de)activate it.
fmtutil [INFO]: exiting with status -1
fmtutil: fmtutil is using the following fmtutil.cnf files (in precedence order):
fmtutil: fmtutil is using the following fmtutil.cnf file for writing changes:
fmtutil:   /etc/texmf/web2c/fmtutil.cnf
fmtutil [INFO]: writing formats under /var/lib/texmf/web2c
fmtutil [INFO]: did not find entry for byfmt=dviluatex, skipped
fmtutil [INFO]: Total formats: 0
fmtutil [INFO]: exiting with status 0
fmtutil: fmtutil is using the following fmtutil.cnf files (in precedence order):
fmtutil: fmtutil is using the following fmtutil.cnf file for writing changes:
fmtutil:   /etc/texmf/web2c/fmtutil.cnf
fmtutil [INFO]: writing formats under /var/lib/texmf/web2c
fmtutil [INFO]: did not find entry for byfmt=etex, skipped
fmtutil [INFO]: Total formats: 0
fmtutil [INFO]: exiting with status 0
fmtutil: fmtutil is using the following fmtutil.cnf files (in precedence order):
fmtutil: fmtutil is using the following fmtutil.cnf file for writing changes:
fmtutil:   /etc/texmf/web2c/fmtutil.cnf
fmtutil [INFO]: writing formats under /var/lib/texmf/web2c
fmtutil [INFO]: did not find entry for byfmt=luajittex, skipped
fmtutil [INFO]: Total formats: 0
fmtutil [INFO]: exiting with status 0
fmtutil: fmtutil is using the following fmtutil.cnf files (in precedence order):
fmtutil: fmtutil is using the following fmtutil.cnf file for writing changes:
fmtutil:   /etc/texmf/web2c/fmtutil.cnf
fmtutil [INFO]: writing formats under /var/lib/texmf/web2c
fmtutil [INFO]: did not find entry for byfmt=luatex, skipped
fmtutil [INFO]: Total formats: 0
fmtutil [INFO]: exiting with status 0
fmtutil: fmtutil is using the following fmtutil.cnf files (in precedence order):
fmtutil: fmtutil is using the following fmtutil.cnf file for writing changes:
fmtutil:   /etc/texmf/web2c/fmtutil.cnf
fmtutil [INFO]: writing formats under /var/lib/texmf/web2c
fmtutil [INFO]: did not find entry for byfmt=mf, skipped
fmtutil [INFO]: Total formats: 0
fmtutil [INFO]: exiting with status 0
fmtutil: fmtutil is using the following fmtutil.cnf files (in precedence order):
fmtutil: fmtutil is using the following fmtutil.cnf file for writing changes:
fmtutil:   /etc/texmf/web2c/fmtutil.cnf
fmtutil [INFO]: writing formats under /var/lib/texmf/web2c
fmtutil [INFO]: did not find entry for byfmt=pdfetex, skipped
fmtutil [INFO]: Total formats: 0
fmtutil [INFO]: exiting with status 0
fmtutil: fmtutil is using the following fmtutil.cnf files (in precedence order):
fmtutil: fmtutil is using the following fmtutil.cnf file for writing changes:
fmtutil:   /etc/texmf/web2c/fmtutil.cnf
fmtutil [INFO]: writing formats under /var/lib/texmf/web2c
fmtutil [INFO]: did not find entry for byfmt=pdftex, skipped
fmtutil [INFO]: Total formats: 0
fmtutil [INFO]: exiting with status 0
fmtutil: fmtutil is using the following fmtutil.cnf files (in precedence order):
fmtutil: fmtutil is using the following fmtutil.cnf file for writing changes:
fmtutil:   /etc/texmf/web2c/fmtutil.cnf
fmtutil [INFO]: writing formats under /var/lib/texmf/web2c
fmtutil [INFO]: did not find entry for byfmt=tex, skipped
fmtutil [INFO]: Total formats: 0
fmtutil [INFO]: exiting with status 0
Running /etc/postinstall/texlive-collection-latex.sh
fmtutil: fmtutil is using the following fmtutil.cnf files (in precedence order):
fmtutil: fmtutil is using the following fmtutil.cnf file for writing changes:
fmtutil:   /etc/texmf/web2c/fmtutil.cnf
fmtutil [WARNING]: Format/engine combination latex/pdftex is not defined.
fmtutil [WARNING]: Cannot (de)activate it.
fmtutil [INFO]: exiting with status -1
fmtutil: fmtutil is using the following fmtutil.cnf files (in precedence order):
fmtutil: fmtutil is using the following fmtutil.cnf file for writing changes:
fmtutil:   /etc/texmf/web2c/fmtutil.cnf
fmtutil [WARNING]: Format/engine combination pdflatex/pdftex is not defined.
fmtutil [WARNING]: Cannot (de)activate it.
fmtutil [INFO]: exiting with status -1
fmtutil: fmtutil is using the following fmtutil.cnf files (in precedence order):
fmtutil: fmtutil is using the following fmtutil.cnf file for writing changes:
fmtutil:   /etc/texmf/web2c/fmtutil.cnf
fmtutil [WARNING]: Format/engine combination dvilualatex/luatex is not defined.
fmtutil [WARNING]: Cannot (de)activate it.
fmtutil [INFO]: exiting with status -1
fmtutil: fmtutil is using the following fmtutil.cnf files (in precedence order):
fmtutil: fmtutil is using the following fmtutil.cnf file for writing changes:
fmtutil:   /etc/texmf/web2c/fmtutil.cnf
fmtutil [WARNING]: Format/engine combination lualatex/luatex is not defined.
fmtutil [WARNING]: Cannot (de)activate it.
fmtutil [INFO]: exiting with status -1
fmtutil: fmtutil is using the following fmtutil.cnf files (in precedence order):
fmtutil: fmtutil is using the following fmtutil.cnf file for writing changes:
fmtutil:   /etc/texmf/web2c/fmtutil.cnf
fmtutil [WARNING]: Format/engine combination mptopdf/pdftex is not defined.
fmtutil [WARNING]: Cannot (de)activate it.
fmtutil [INFO]: exiting with status -1
fmtutil: fmtutil is using the following fmtutil.cnf files (in precedence order):
fmtutil: fmtutil is using the following fmtutil.cnf file for writing changes:
fmtutil:   /etc/texmf/web2c/fmtutil.cnf
fmtutil [INFO]: writing formats under /var/lib/texmf/web2c
fmtutil [INFO]: did not find entry for byfmt=dvilualatex, skipped
fmtutil [INFO]: Total formats: 0
fmtutil [INFO]: exiting with status 0
fmtutil: fmtutil is using the following fmtutil.cnf files (in precedence order):
fmtutil: fmtutil is using the following fmtutil.cnf file for writing changes:
fmtutil:   /etc/texmf/web2c/fmtutil.cnf
fmtutil [INFO]: writing formats under /var/lib/texmf/web2c
fmtutil [INFO]: did not find entry for byfmt=latex, skipped
fmtutil [INFO]: Total formats: 0
fmtutil [INFO]: exiting with status 0
fmtutil: fmtutil is using the following fmtutil.cnf files (in precedence order):
fmtutil: fmtutil is using the following fmtutil.cnf file for writing changes:
fmtutil:   /etc/texmf/web2c/fmtutil.cnf
fmtutil [INFO]: writing formats under /var/lib/texmf/web2c
fmtutil [INFO]: did not find entry for byfmt=lualatex, skipped
fmtutil [INFO]: Total formats: 0
fmtutil [INFO]: exiting with status 0
fmtutil: fmtutil is using the following fmtutil.cnf files (in precedence order):
fmtutil: fmtutil is using the following fmtutil.cnf file for writing changes:
fmtutil:   /etc/texmf/web2c/fmtutil.cnf
fmtutil [INFO]: writing formats under /var/lib/texmf/web2c
fmtutil [INFO]: did not find entry for byfmt=mptopdf, skipped
fmtutil [INFO]: Total formats: 0
fmtutil [INFO]: exiting with status 0
fmtutil: fmtutil is using the following fmtutil.cnf files (in precedence order):
fmtutil: fmtutil is using the following fmtutil.cnf file for writing changes:
fmtutil:   /etc/texmf/web2c/fmtutil.cnf
fmtutil [INFO]: writing formats under /var/lib/texmf/web2c
fmtutil [INFO]: did not find entry for byfmt=pdflatex, skipped
fmtutil [INFO]: Total formats: 0
fmtutil [INFO]: exiting with status 0
```

The following texlive packages are installed:

```
texlive-collection-basic
texlive-collection-latex-doc
texlive-collection-latex
texlive
```

I feel like I'm missing something. I've not really found any cygwin tutorials on getting set up, but assumed that linux tutorials would cover the same steps. These all seem to suggest that after installation the package is ready to use.

edit: [This arch forum post](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=142060) had a few useful hints. I ran

```
mktexmf --all
texhash
```

And then had 50 disabled formats. I enabled latex and pdflatex, however then when I run `fmtutil-sys --all` I'm informed about missing packages. I will investigate further.

edit2: The missing files are all hyphenation files in languages I have no interest in using. For lack of a better idea I'm installing the language files one by one, but if someone can tell me how to avoid doing that I'd be very grateful.

Comment: [Similar question there](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/304178). Hints given here or there might be applicable to the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If really in trouble during the installation, then it's always safer to reinstall.

I had a similar problem (and INFO from `mktexfmt` was the same). First of all, check whether `latex.fmt` is actually present in your installation (use `locate` or `find` for that - probably they are present in `cygwin`).

If the file exists, then the problem may be that `kpathsea` [can't find](http://tug.org/texinfohtml/kpathsea.html#Unable-to-find-files) your files. Run

```
kpsewhich --debug -1 latex.fmt
```

kdebug shows search path for fmt files (from texmf.cnf).
Alternatively you can run

```
kpsewhich --show-path=fmt
```

Try to set

```
export TEXMF=.:/opt/tex/cur//:
```

where last two slashes mean subdirectory expansion (substitute your own path instead of mine). In my case that immediately helped.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Coming back to this I can't reproduce the problem. It could be that my distribution fixed a bug or that I did something all that time ago that solved things, but can't remember. In any case I'll mark your answer as correct since it is likely it would have solved the issue.

Comment: Did not work for me on ubuntu.